# max iteritems and key attribute in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following dictionary gh, Why I am getting different outputs with and without key attributes. What is that key attribute doing here??

```
gh = {'LF': 11483, 'C': 10886, 'DH': 7558, 'SS': 11259, 'OF': 26418, 'CF': 7552, 'P': 42586, 'RF': 10307, '1B': 13087, '2B': 12348, '3B': 13507}

max(gh.iteritems(), key = lambda x: x[1])

output: ('P', 42586)
```

Without key :

```
max(gh.iteritems(), key = lambda x: x[1])
output : ('SS', 11259)
```

Comment: you might have forgotten to remove `key` parameter in the second code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the key as `lambda x: x[1]`, your code picks the items based on the maximum of the dict values. This is, of course, 42586.

However, without the key, the maximum is chosen from the keys of the dict. The "maximum" is the key 'SS', since it's lexicographically bigger than any other key.

Edit: as DSM pointed out in the comments, without `key` specified, the comparison actually uses the whole `(key, value)` pair of iteritems(). However, the uniqueness of each key essentially makes this a comparison of the keys, since `value` is never needed for tie-breaking.

Comment: @DSM - But when I use gh.items() I get the maximum value, without using the key attribute, which one should I use then? I know that iteritems returns a generator. but I am still confused which one to use

Comment: @ElizabethSusanJoseph: no, you don't get the maximum value without the `key`--  `max({1: 10, 100: 2}.items()) == (100, 2)`.  There's no difference here between using `.items()` and `.iteritems()` with respect to the presence or absence of `key`.

Comment: @Elizabeth a general rule always use `iteritems` when you can, it's usually most efficient. It's an iterator so it doesn't need to build a list first. But you really could use either

Comment: @DSM- Got it, I will better use .iteritems always.